# angular navigation (editing items list)--NOT WORKING

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I am a beginner on Ionic/Angularjs.
Developing a side menu app on windows 10.
I populated a page from a select statement on SQLite.
And i'm to edit individual item by navigating to an edit page using state params but not responding. Many thanks for your kind assistance:

```
<a href="#/edit/{{task.id}}" class="item" ng-repeat="task in Ourdata">
        <h2>{{task.id}}</h2>
        <p>{{task.name}}</p>
</a>
```

```js
.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider){
    $stateProvider
      .state('list',{
        url: '/list',
        templateUrl: 'templates/list.html'
      })
    .state('edit',{
      url: '/edit:taskId',
      templateUrl: 'templates/edit.html'
     });
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/list');
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should insert the slash `/` before the `:`

I edited and add a controller to it:

```
.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider){
    $stateProvider
      .state('list',{
        url: '/list',
        templateUrl: 'templates/list.html'
      })
    .state('edit',{
      url: '/edit/:taskId',
      templateUrl: 'templates/edit.html',
      controller: 'MyCtrl'
     });
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/list');
})
```

In your controller:

```
.controller('MyCtrl', function($stateParams){
    var taskId = $stateParams.taskId;
});
```